# How to find the limit sum of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose

$$S_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\exp(i/2)}{\sum_{j=1}^{i}\exp(j/2)} \ \ \ \text{where} \ \   i = 1,\ldots,n$$

Programatically, $S_n\approx 0.49$ but would I show this by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you mean to ask about the following limit:
$$
S=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{n/2}}{e^{1/2}+\cdots+e^{n/2}}.
$$
Using the geometric series formula $1+r+\cdots+r^{n-1}=\frac{r^{n}-1}{r-1}$ with $r=e^{1/2}$, we obtain that
$$
\frac{e^{n/2}}{e^{1/2}+\cdots+e^{n/2}}=\frac{e^{1/2}-1}{e^{1/2}}\frac{e^{n/2}}{e^{n/2}-1},
$$
which tends to $1-e^{-1/2}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Wolfy the expression you wrote coincides with the one I wrote, since $e^{-1/2}=1/e^{1/2}=1/\sqrt{e}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have that from summing the denominator as a geometric series for general $a$:

$$\lim_{i\to\infty}\frac{a^i}{\sum_{j=1}^{i}a^j}=(a-1)\lim_{i\to\infty}\frac{a^i}{a^{i+1}-a}=\frac{a-1}{a}$$

and thus for the present problem $$\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\approx 0.39$$